# Select indexes of all elements in sequence

Tags: c#, linq, select, indexing

Using LINQ, can I write a statement that will return an IEnumerable of the indexes of items.

Very simple instance:

```
{1,2,4,5,3}
```

would just return

```
{0,1,2,3,4}
```

and

```
{1,2,4,5,3}.Where(num => num == 4)
```

would return

```
{2}
```

It isn't exact code, but it should get the idea across.

Comment: If the collection is IEnumerable, it won't be efficient. Must be copied into an array or a list.

Comment: would this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx

Comment: Really you asked this question? any Linq document contains many similar examples.

Comment: Also, you must know the range of the array that you're working on, or have a copy of the sorted array while also having the unsorted array to check indices of.

Comment: @I4V, please post a link.

Comment: @MikeCole do you really need one? As I implied, google for it. Before asking a question make your own homework and search.

Comment: This is one of those "you wouldn't use Linq for that" things.

Comment: @I4V based on the answers it's not as clear-cut as you rudely implied.

Comment: @MikeCole It is as clear-cut as I implied, but on SO, simple Linq answers get many reps. So this is why you see so many answers (Easy to read, easy to answer).

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var a = new[] {1, 2, 4, 5, 3};

//** First, generates a simple sequence with {0,1,2,3,4} 
//** using the 2 parameter lambda select

var sequence1 = a.Select((_, index) => index);

//** Second, gets an array with all indexes where the value is 4.

// We need both value and index for the next line to work.
var sequence2 = a.Select((value, index) => new {value, index});

// Get all indexes where the value is 4
var indexArray = sequence2.Where(x => x.value == 4)
                          .Select(x => x.index).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Ric Sorry, I realize my answer was a bit confusing, the first part just shows that you can select the index to get `{0,1,2,3,4}` as the question states, the second sequence along with the `WriteLine` solves the "select index where value is x" which the question also asks for. Of course, if the value repeats, you'll need to do `ToArray()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()` to get them all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to change up your syntax a bit and use an extension method, the following will work. I'm not keen on it as it creates a new sequence for every call.

```
var sequence = new[] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 3 };

sequence.Indexer().Select(num => num.Item1); // returns {0,1,2,3,4}
sequence.Indexer().Where(num => num.Item2 == 4).Select(num => num.Item1); // returns {2}

private static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, T>> Indexer<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    return sequence.Select((x, y) => new Tuple<int, T>(y, x));
}
```

A better way would be to change up the way you're writing it altogether:

```
var sequence = new[] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 3 };

sequence.Select((num, index) => new { Num = num, Index = index }).Select(num => num.Index); // returns {0, 1,2,3,4}
sequence.Select((num, index) => new { Num = num, Index = index }).Where(num => num.Num == 4).Select(num => num.Index); // returns {2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToList();

int index = -1;

var indices = numbers.Select(x => i++).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<int> seq = new[] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 3 };

// The indexes of all elements.
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, seq.Count());

// The index of the left-most element with value 4.
// NOTE: Will return seq.Count() if the element doesn't exist.
var index = seq.TakeWhile(x => x != 4).Count();

// The indexes of all the elements with value 4.
// NOTE: Be careful to enumerate only once.
int current_index = 0;
var all_indexes =
    from e in (
        from x in seq
        select new { x, Index = current_index++ }
    )
    where e.x == 4
    select e.Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

The full set of indices just depends on the number of items, not on the values, so you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<int> indices = Enumerable.Range(0, 5);
```

If you're dealing with an `IEnumerable<T>`, you could do the following to get the index of the item matching 4:

```
IEnumerable<int> values = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int indexOf4 = (
    values.Select((v, i) => new {v, i})
          .FirstOrDefault(vi => vi.v == 4) ?? new {v = 0, i = -1}).i;
```

This copes with the case where the value source doesn't contain a match (returning -1).

Of course, if you don't mind converting your `IEnumerable<T>` to a list then you can just call `IndexOf`:

```
int indexOf4a = values.ToList().IndexOf(4);
```

---

But, I suspect what the question is really looking for is a way to find **all the indices** for values that match a particular predicate. For example:

```
IEnumerable<int> big = values.Select((v, i) => new {v, i})
                             .Where(vi => vi.v > 3)
                             .Select (vi => vi.i);
```

which returns the indices of the values `> 3`: `[3, 4]`.

If the predicate doesn't match any values then you'll get an empty enumerable as the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> WhereIndices<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return source.Select(Tuple.Create<T, int>)
        .Where(z => predicate(z.Item1)).Select(z => z.Item2);
}
```

It's an extension method, so put it in a static non-nested class. Use it just like you use `Where`, that is:

```
.WhereIndices(num => num == 4)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it. Not sure how efficient it is though..

```
List<int> list = new List<int>()
{
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
};

var indexes = list.Select(item => list.IndexOf(item));

var index = list.Where(item => item == 4).Select(item => list.IndexOf(item));
```

Comment: You seem to be the only guy that understood the question for real. Btw, you can `Select(list.IndexOf)` for short.

Comment: -1 `list.Select(item => list.IndexOf(item));` I can't think of worse way.

Comment: `O(n^2)`, so not efficient at all, because the problem is linear.